# How to iterate in subitems of a object in a django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

views.py:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Servico


class ServicoView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Servico
    context_object_name = 'servico'
    template_name = 'servico.html'
```

models.py:

```
from djongo import models


class PublicoAlvo(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return ''
    alvo1 = models.CharField(max_length = 126)
    alvo2 = models.CharField(max_length = 126, blank = True, default = '')
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Servico(models.Model):
    t_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True, unique = True, max_length = 252)
    alvos = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container = PublicoAlvo
    )
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('servicos/<slug:pk>/', views.ServicoView.as_view(), name = 'servico')
]
```

I think these are the relevant files in my Django app folder. Back to the question, how can I iterate over the values that are going to be stored in `servico.alvos` in my template? If I want to show `t_id`, I just use `{{ servico.t_id }}` and it works fine. I could write something like:

```
<HTML1>
{{ servico.alvos.alvo1 }}
<HTML2>
<HTML1>
{{ servico.alvos.alvo2 }}
<HTML2>
```

And that would show the values that I want, but would make things uglier, since I would have to write a lot of repeated standard HTML (that I indicated as  and ) to format each value inside `servico.alvos`, and more limited (imagine if I decide to change the model and add more 6 values in the PublicoAlvo class). I tried the following:

```
{% for alvo in servico.alvos.all %}
    <HTML1>
    {{ alvo }}
    <HTML2>
{% endfor %}
```

and

```
{% for alvo in servico.alvos.items %}
    <HTML1>
    {{ alvo }}
    <HTML2>
{% endfor %}
```

But I get nothing printed. When I try:

```
{% for alvo in servico.alvos %}
    <HTML1>
    {{ alvo }}
    <HTML2>
{% endfor %}
```

I get `'PublicoAlvo' object is not iterable`

Is there a way to get what I want using a loop in my template or changing something in my `models.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the first answer of [Niel Godfrey Ponciano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11043825/niel-godfrey-ponciano), I was able to solve the problem.

models.py:

```
from djongo import models


class PublicoAlvo(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return ''
    def list(self):
        return [value for key, value in self.__dict__.items() if not key.startswith('_')] 
    alvo1 = models.CharField(max_length = 126)
    alvo2 = models.CharField(max_length = 126, blank = True, default = '')
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Servico(models.Model):
    t_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True, unique = True, max_length = 252)
    alvos = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container = PublicoAlvo
    )
```

And then I can iterate over `servico.alvos.list` using a `for` in the template just by adding the `list` method that returns the relevant fields (variables) values in my class.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{{ servico.t_id }}
{{ servico.alvos }}
```

Then in your models.py

```
class PublicoAlvo(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        # Option 1: List all <alvo> fields
        return ", ".join(
            [
                self.alvo1,
                self.alvo2,
            ]
        )

        # Option 2: If you don't like manually listing each <alvo> field
        # return ", ".join(
        #     [
        #         getattr(self, f"alvo{index}") for index in range(1, 3)
        #     ]
        # )

    ...
```

This might give something like

```
The value for alvo1, While for alvo2 is this one
```

---

**Update**

You could also try

```
{% for key, value in servico.alvos.items %}
    {% if key|slice:":4" == "alvo" %}
        {{ value }}<br>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This might show something like

```
The value for alvo1
While for alvo2 is this one
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The thing is that I want to access each value separately in my template using a loop. I will update the question to better clarify

Comment: I updated the answer. Could you try if it works?

Comment: This time, did not work. But your previous answer was extremely helpful. Based on it, I was able to write a solution. I will put it here as an answer